# How to parse tags with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example i've this string:

`#fox #fo x  #fox # fox   #  fox`

how can i get string look like this:

`fox fox fox fox fox`

I can't remove extra spaces correct

UPD: because when i delete '#', i get empty space like `fox  fox`

Comment: What is your trial? How is /[\s]+/ /

Comment: thx for fast answer but i update question

Comment: See Wachington's answer. And remember `g` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all spaces not before the hash this way:

```
\s(?!#)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/cX3lV8/1)

And if you also want to match the hash:

```
\s(?!#)|#
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/cX3lV8/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would strip out the spaces and split on `#`, then join again:

```
function get_hash(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, '') . split(`#`) . join(' ') . slice(1);
}

var s = '#fox #fo x  #fox # fox   #  fox';
get_hash(s)
"fox fox fox fox fox"
```